# window.location.href not returning anything after the "&" character

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I don't have much experience with javascript and I am trying to return the current url to redirect back. As long as there are no more than one parameter on the page the url sent back is fine. But when there's an & character everything after the & is always cut. Is there a way to make it return the parameters or do I need to find an alternative way of getting the full url?

I'm calling it like this within a function:

```
var currentPage = window.location.href;
```

What is in the url:

```
  https://localhost:5001/AdvisementSession/ScheduleAdvisementSession?studentid=7&studentholdid=7&generaladvisorid=4&facultyadvisorid=2
```

What window.location.href returns:

```
https://localhost:5001/AdvisementSession/ScheduleAdvisementSession?studentid=7
```

The code I'm working with:

```
 var defaultSettings = $.extend({
            NotificationList: [],
            NotiFromPropName: "",
            ListTitlePropName: "",
            ListBodyPropName: "",
            RemoveNotificationLink: "",
            ControllerName: "Notifications",
            ActionName: "ClearAllNotifications"
            
        }, options);
        var parentId = $(this).attr("id");
        if ($.trim(parentId) != "" && parentId.length > 0) {
            $("#" + parentId + " .ikrNotifications .ikrClearAll").click(function () {
               var currentPage = window.location.href;
               window.location.href = '/Notifications/ClearAllNotifications?returnUrl=' + currentPage;
            });
```

As far as frameworks I'm using asp.net core mvc  to build the app in .net core 5.0.

I'm using an external plug in I got from a tutorial for the java script side and am just editing it to learn java script slowly. The click function should just be getting the url then setting the location's href to controller and action I'm trying to call which has a parameter "returnUrl" which it gets there fine but the url is always cut if there's a & symbol.

The action method inside of the notifications controller:

```
  public IActionResult ClearAllNotifications(string returnUrl)
{
    //TODO start here
    this._oNotifications.Clear();
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: It should return the whole thing. Can you post the code where you try to use it? If you open a dev console on Google and do a search and look at window.location, you can see window.location.href has the entire url, your search string, and other parameters. So it might be something you're doing to try to use the property.

Comment: It looks like you're not posting a full example of your code. But in general, you'll need to use `encodeURI` and `decodeURI` when working with full URLs like that in JavaScript, to reliably retain all parameters and special characters.

Comment: Are you using a front end framework that is modifying the query string after you try inspecting the href?

Comment: @Nikki9696 it does in fact say that the window.location has the entire url parameters and all. so it may very well be something that is being edited elsewhere that I'm unaware of. I'll inspect the code more and see what I can find.

Comment: @RyanLaB Thanks for the tip. I ended up needing to use encodeUIRComponet but didn't have to decode it. I've only ever asked a question on stack overflow once sorry for not pointing enough info the first time around. I'll mark this as resolved as soon as I figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

Using `encodeURIComponent();` solved the issue.

<sub>Answer given by [@RyanLaB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035173/ryan-lab) on comment.</sub>